# SailsJS Association on MYSQL

Tags: mysql, associations, sails.js

I have a MySQL database that was previously used for production, and right now our team is migrating to SailsJS. I've read about sails' association and I think it is great. But I was wondering if you can use the association to populate the connected tables using the `.populate` method. I've tried it by adding

```
user: {
   model: 'User'
}
```

to my profile model. But when I tried populating it by using the populate method. It generates an error.

```
"error": "E_UNKNOWN",
"status": 500,
"summary": "Encountered an unexpected error",
"raw": {
  "code": "ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR",
  "errno": 1054,
  "sqlState": "42S22",
  "index": 0
}
```

Here are the two mysql table schemas
For the user table:

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user` (
   `userId` int(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `email` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `locationId` int(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` tinyint(4) NOT NULL COMMENT '0 - inactive, 1 - active, 2 - delete',
  `companyId` int(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `createDate` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`userId`),
  UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`),
  KEY `fk_locationId` (`locationId`),
  KEY `fk_orgId` (`companyId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=259 ;
```

For the profile table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `profile` (
  `profileId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `firstName` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `lastName` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `suffix` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `nickName` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `title` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Name Title, e.g, Dr., Engr., etc\n',
  `userId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `birthDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `phoneNumber` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dateUpdated` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `image` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `gender` tinyint(1) NOT NULL COMMENT '0 - female, 1 - male',
  `middleName` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `telephoneNumber` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`profileId`),
  KEY `fk_userId` (`userId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=259 ;

ALTER TABLE `profile`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_userId` FOREIGN KEY (`userId`) REFERENCES `user` (`userId`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

**Update**

[User](http://pastebin.com/bcHgiWtP) Model

[Profile](http://pastebin.com/RefCrC9X) Model

Comment: Take a look at [the docs](http://beta.sailsjs.org/#!documentation/reference/ModelAssociations/One-to-Many.html).  Your syntax is wrong; the `model` attribute should be a string which is the identity of the model to associate, e.g. `model: 'user'`

Comment: Oh yeah. I just forgot to put apostrophe on the User. But no. It still does not work.

Comment: It needs to be lowercase `user`.  Is it lowercase?  Also, can you post the error you're seeing?

Comment: Anyway, I don't think the case is the issue since I assigned the first letter of the model to be capitalized.

Comment: It matters. Unless you specifically set an `identity` property in the model definition, the model identity is lowercased, regardless of what the globalized class name is.

Comment: Yes, but I've tried using the lowercase 'user' but it still does not work. Have you tried the sailsjs association yourself with the mySQL?

Comment: Just narrowing it down.  Yes, associations should work fine with MySQL.  It looks like the table might be missing the foreign key field, which Sails should be creating for you provided you don't have `migrate: safe` specified in your connection config.  Can you post the full model definition, and the MySQL table schema you're seeing for that model?

Comment: Should it really make a difference when I assign migrate to safe. Because according to my observation, waterline adds a new column when you don't assign the migrate to `safe`.

Comment: Yes, that's the point--you need that migration to happen, or else you need to tell Sails more about your schema.  See my answer below for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you may not be using the latest version of Sails beta (rc7), which may have provided you with slightly better error messages (like which field was causing the error).

In any case, it would appear that you need a bit of database migration to get things working with Sails.  You can have Waterline do this for you--in fact it will do it by default if you don't have the `migrate: safe` attribute in your connection configuration.  But in your case, as is often true when migrating projects, you already have a schema and you'd probably rather not have Waterline mess with it.  No problem--we just need to tweak some settings in your model configurations and you should be good to go.

**In api/models/Profile.js:**

```
module.exports = {
    autoPK: false,        // don't try and add a unique ID; we already have one 
    autoCreatedAt: false, // don't try and add a createdAt timestamp
    autoUpdatedAt: false, // don't try and add a updatedAt timestamp
    attributes: {
        profileId: {
            type: 'integer',
            primaryKey: true
        },
        user: {
            model: 'user',
            columnName: 'userId'
        },
        ...etc...
    }
}
```

**In api/models/User.js:**

```
module.exports = {
    autoPK: false,        // don't try and add a unique ID; we already have one 
    autoCreatedAt: false, // don't try and add a createdAt timestamp
    autoUpdatedAt: false, // don't try and add a updatedAt timestamp
    attributes: {
        userId: {
            type: 'integer',
            primaryKey: true
        }
        profile: {
            model: 'profile',
            columnName: 'profileId'
        },
        ...etc...
    }
}
```

Note that Sails doesn't currently support true one-to-one relationships, so you'll have to link both sides individually if you want to populate both ways.  That is, adding a profile with `user: 1` won't let you do `User.findOne(1).populate('profile')`; you'll have to set the `profile` key on user #1 explicitly in order for that to work.

Comment: Could you please expound this sentence: `you'll have to set the profile key on user #1 explicitly in order for that to work.` I'm sorry I'm a bit new to sails. So does that mean that `User.findOne(1).populate('profile')` will still not work?

Comment: The above code will give you the ability to use associations in Sails with your current DB.  I'm just noting that for a *new* profile record with `userId` set to 1, you can do `Profile.findOne([new profile id]).populate('user')`, but you won't automatically be able to do `User.findOne(1).populate('profile')`.  In order for that to work, you'd still need to update user #1's `profileId` to be that of the new profile record; Waterline won't do that for you.  This is in contrast to many-to-one or many-to-many associations, where you can use the `via` key to specify inverse associations.

Comment: Full docs for Sails associations [here](http://beta.sailsjs.org/#!documentation/reference/ModelAssociations/ModelAssociations.html).

Comment: Thank you for your answer and link, btw the example that you gave is it really like that or did you happened to interchange the two? I've also updated my profile and user models